# How to receive string as function result while calling Delphi code with asm?

Tags: delphi, assembly

I'm studying assembly in Delphi and I got in a situation.
When I call a object function that returns a string I get an "access violation", but when the function returns an integer everything goes ok.

This is the code:

```
type
  TAsmTest = class(TObject)
    function CallText: string;
  end;

  TForm40 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure CallName(Test: TAsmTest);
  end;

var
  Form40: TForm40;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm40.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Test: TAsmTest;
begin
  Test := TAsmTest.Create;
  CallName(Test);
end;

procedure TForm40.CallName(Test: TAsmTest);
asm
  push eax;

  mov eax, edx;
  call TAsmTest.CallText;  //Error doesn't happen here
  call ShowMessage

  pop eax;
end;

{ TClassText }

function TAsmTest.CallText: string;
begin
  Result := 'Test Text'; //The Result content is inaccessible, and I dont know why. The EAX is ok.
end;
```

Any material will be also welcome, by now I'm using this as reference: 
http://www.guidogybels.eu/a

Comment: I suggest you write the code in plain Pascal first and then study the assembly that the compiler generates, then you can rewrite thel code to use similar assembly. Return values of non-trivial types are handled differently than you are expecting. And BTW, you guide link is broken.

Comment: I'm doing this as well, but there some generated code that aren't that easy to just understand how they work. For instance the reservation of the stack value in the start, etc. So documentation helps a lot. And it's strange in this case, the caller must take care of the return pointer of the calling function ?

Comment: Some one tagged my question as duplicated, pay attention. The one mentioned question returns a long string, I'm not returning long strings I'm receiving it as result...

Comment: Also I'm calling this from an object, not using pure functions

Comment: Indeed, the question that @Remy flagged as a dupe is a different question...

Comment: You are returning a long string. And a method is just a function with an implicit Self parameter passed before the others. So yes, it is a dupe.

Comment: I'm not returning a long string from my assembly code. My code is: I have an assembly procedure that receives an long string from a regular method. My doubt is on my assembly method that is receiving the string. How do I RECEIVE a long string from a regular method using an assembly method.

Comment: That's just the other side of the same thing. It's a var parameter, passed after all the other parameters. You did read the documentation right?

Comment: David did you see what I'm trying to do in my example ? It's not about the var object. It's about the string, I saw that in the other answer they created the string etc etc, that not my problem.  my problem happens when I call the class function from an assembly code, the return throws an error while assigning the string in the result. But it's in the regular function that I get the error, this that I can't understand

Comment: @RodrigoFariasRezino: Delphi's `string` type is a "long string" by default, as opposed to a "short string". `CallText()` is returning a `string`. Delphi returns a `string` from a function/method by using a hidden `var` parameter, not the `EAX` register. Your assembly code does not account for that. It needs to allocate and initialize a local `string` variable and then pass a pointer to that variable in `EDX` to `CallText()` (the `Self` pointer to the `TAsmText` object must be passed in `EAX`).

Comment: @RodrigoFariasRezino: From the compiler's perspective, `CallText()` is essentially implemented internally as if it were a standalone function with this signature: `procedure CallText(Self: TAsmTest; var Result: string);`, so your assembly code has to call it accordingly. Again, if you write normal Pascal code and then study the compiler's generated assembly, you would see this.

Comment: @RodrigoFariasRezino: I am the one who marked this question as a duplicate. The other question explains how a `string` return value from a function/method using Delphi's default `register` calling convention gets passed into and out of the function/method at the assembly layer.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @RemyLebeau, I'm try to do it here.